# Flutter project not picking up local flutter package updates

Tags: flutter

Flutter 3.3.9

I created a flutter project and I reference it as a dependency in another flutter project like so:

```
      dev_dependencies:
          flutter_test:
            sdk: flutter
          my_utils:
            path: ../my_utils
```

When I added the local package to my project initially, I could see and debug the referenced local package just fine. I made updates to the my_utils package, did a "flutter pub get" in the project referencing my_utils, and the changes are not being picked up.

I added a new class to my_utils and it is not finding it in the other project.

I have this in analysis_options.yaml:

```
include: package:flutter_lints/flutter.yaml

linter:
  rules:
     depend_on_referenced_packages: false
```

Setting depend_on_referenced_packages to true didn't help.

How do I make my changes/updates in my_utils show in my referencing project?

Thanks

Comment: Every dependency is cached in .dart_cache (or similar), so, in order to retrieve your updates in the new project you should do everytime a `flutter pub upgrade`(edited after @RoslanAmir suggestion)

Comment: Do you mean `flutter pub upgrade`?

Comment: @RoslanAmir yup you're right

Comment: first, i changed the version number, then ran flutter pub upgrade and it changed the version. I still had to manually add the import statement. VSCode normally will show you the available imports.

Comment: @GicuAftene with respect but that's not correct! i use several packages the same way and updates appears right away, with even running `flutter pub get` (except for dependency changes)

Comment: @MichaelSoliman i missunderstood the question lol in fact i didn't see the part where he actually does a `flutter pub get`. Btw pub get and pub upgrade are not the same in fact pub get, if a dependency or a package area locked in lock file it will not be considered. but `flutter pub upgrade` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you export the files properly ? e.g files inside `src/`?

my_utils file structure should be like the following:

```
lib/
...src/
......my_impl.dart
...my_utils.dart
```

and in your `my_utils.dart` should contain the following:

```
export 'src/my_impl.dart';
```

I recommend you use [melos](https://melos.invertase.dev/) for managing multi-package projects. it might solve your problem. Also with `melos bootstrap`, you get `flutter pub get` running in all packages with one command.

you can follow the installation from [here](https://melos.invertase.dev/getting-started#installation)

Comment: the flutter pub upgrade is what i needed.

Comment: that should be a one time issue then, since updates are visible right away when you make any change.

Comment: In my_utils.dart, i'm exporting correctly and my code structure looks fine. I created the my_utils project like any other flutter project "flutter create my_utils" Should i do something differently for  a package to use in other projects?

Comment: should be the same as any package, but try using `melos` it will save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: I marked your answer the answer. Thank you for politely correcting me

Comment: OMG, i'm in love with Melos. I followed this  https://dev.to/leehack/start-the-monorepo-flutter-project-1eo9 and it's working like a charm. Thanks once again